# C# Process.Start With argument is running the exe constructor that has no arguments

Tags: c#, constructor, process

I have an application 'A' that contains 2 constructors, one takes no argument and the other takes 2 arguments

I use the application 'A' as a sand alone app or to be ran by another application 'B'

When I call the process.start function and pass the arguments the code only run the constructor with no arguments. Any Idea on how to force constructor with argument to be called

Here is the function that call App 'A' from App 'B'

```
 private void RunPartialDeleteProcess(string locationIdForSubscription, string connectionStringOfNewlyCopiedHive)
    {
        string applicationPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +"\\PartialDelete";
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            applicationPath = @"D:\Data\bin\x64\Debug";
        }
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName =Path.Combine(applicationPath, "PartialDeleteToolUI.exe");
        startInfo.Arguments = $"{locationIdForSubscription} {connectionStringOfNewlyCopiedHive}";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Here is the class for App 'A'

```
public partial class frmParialDeleteTool : Form
{

    public frmParialDeleteTool()
    {
       Console.WriteLn("Hello 1")
    }

    public frmParialDeleteTool(string location, string connectionString)
    {

        Console.WriteLn("Hello 2")
    }
}
```

The Result is always Hello 1

Thanks 
Jp

Comment: Where/how do you instantiate `frmParialDeleteTool`? Starting a process doesn't invoke any constructor, it just starts at `Main`.

Comment: [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: When you run a winforms app, it calls the `Main()` method on Program.cs, which will call the argumentless Form constructor.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I didn't pay attention to the Main. I did fix it.